# Proper handling of Gigantic input & processing strings

Tags: java, string

I've been looking for days on solving some key problems I'm running into, and I have not found a good answer for this problem yet.

I'm embarking on an academic (/learning) project that involves reading 3-50MB plain-text files on a regular basis, and eventually across millions of records (my current set is ~800,000 records)

Assuming the file *can't* be `split()` into chunks, what's the best way to pass this this chunk between functions? Pass-by-value leads me to think (and, I believe, see) passing a 50MB file to a function, and returning a 20-30MB result set, means I have used wasted over 100MB memory just passing the file that's waiting to be reclaimed at GC. (Technically, the file can be split(), but those split()s are each 10MB large at times, and each must be held while processing)

I've made significant changes to my overall project recently, and I want to design the processing portion **better** this time. Previous method primarily read and processed the data in the driver itself--without a data container. When I attempted to use a data container, I ended up with similar results. Here's the first method I used:

1. Read entire 3-50 MB+ file to String
2. Regex/split into 4-15 chunks (determined by XML-like tags in file)
3. Pass 1-3 chunks to function A (Looking for certain data)
4. Pass 4-5 more chunks to function B (Looking for different data, which won't exist in Function A chunks)
5. Collect results back in driver function
6. Stitched together result set, and wrote to disk (I know now that I should create-and-append instead)

I can probably split as I read, however, even those splits can be 5MB in size each (or more), and I need to keep most of them in memory until the file is done with processing (in case step 3 changes how step 4 works).. and even worse, some input readLine()'s might be 1-2MB long themselves (before the `\n`).

So, what kind of design strategy would be best for handling these huge input files, and huge strings?

Comment: Can't you place the contents of the file into a class, and use the reference of the class when you call methods? Since it's by reference, no more memory with be allocated during method calls.

Comment: I'd be inclined to pass around a [FileReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileReader.html) or some such, and handle the file as a stream.  Or, what with there being XML-like tags, perhaps a [SAX parser](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/sax/index.html) is in order?

Comment: @femtoRgon I'm cautious to XML parse, as these files follow XML standard like a 6 year old writing an HTML page (yay government contractors!). However, passing the read handle is a _very_ interesting idea...

Comment: As @TheGuyWithTheHat stated Java won't duplicate your strings when you pass them to functions. The questions I have are: 1) do you have to use Strings or can you work with char[]? 2) Do you need to use Regex/split? 3) Why not pre-process the data? 4) Do you already run into performance problems or is this a case of premature optimization? 5) What is the type of the data, plain-text is a bit unspecific? 6) What do you do in your functions with it?

Comment: @LeonardBrünings, This (may) be premature? I'm bouncing to 2GB memory usage (90% of which can be gc'ed) just by reading in files, split them (not necessarily with split()), and passing. The data is UTF-8, and lots of historical data. newer historical data is Microsoft Word "HTML" documents (with lots of bad and redundant HTML). And this is actually my "pre-processing" step.. the functions are stripping out bad/image-to-ascii-encoded data (which was appended into .txt). Part of this question is to find other topics to research to avoid regex and split()--which you all are helping at greatly :-)

Comment: @Pseudo if it is HTML you might want to look into http://tidy.sourceforge.net/#docs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Pass-by-value leads me to think (and, I believe, see) passing a 50MB
>   file to a function, and returning a 20-30MB result set, means I have
>   used wasted over 100MB memory just passing the file that's waiting to
>   be reclaimed at GC.

Incorrect. Java passes *references* by value, not the entire `String`. What I would do is pass the (reference to) the string along with the start and end indices of the section of the string you want to process.

```
void read()
{
    String input = /*your code here*/;
    process(input, 37, 17576);
}

process(String input, int startIndex, int endIndex)
{
    /*your code here, e.g.
    for(int i = startIndex; i < endIndex; i++)
    {
        //do stuff
    }*/
}
```

Also, if `read` and `process` are in the same class, you can just make the string a class field:

```
String input;

void read()
{
    input = /*your code here*/;
    process(37, 17576);
}

process(int startIndex, int endIndex)
{
    /*your code here, e.g.
    for(int i = startIndex; i < endIndex; i++)
    {
        //do stuff
    }*/
}
```

Comment: Great ideas! What if I wanted the object to hold onto multiple `process()` results in another string of >5MB in length? would you recommend a List<String> ? or some other type?

Comment: @Pseudo I think a [`LinkedList<String>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) would do the trick. I would avoid using an `ArrayList`, because all the elements of an `ArrayList` are in sequential order, whereas in a `LinkedList` they aren't. The only downside of a `LinkedList` is an extremely small (a few bytes per element) increase in memory usage and another extremely small (on the order of a few nanoseconds) increase in time.